# Handling forgotten passwords when designing desktop applications

Tags: passwords, desktop-application

I'm in the process of creating a traditional desktop application, and I'd like to enable the user to protect the application with a password.

I was wondering what people tend to do in terms of helping the user if they can't remember the password? I don't want them to be locked out of the app entirely because of it.

If I were creating a web app, this wouldn't be an issue as a system could be put in place where an email is sent to them containing their password (after they answer a mother's maiden name type question)

I don't believe this is an option with a desktop app. The person who the end user may not want to access the application would likely know the mother's maiden name or have access to the end user's email account simply by opening Outlook.

I've searched Stack Overflow and Googled but no joy.

I assume there must be a common process used for such situations but I'm buggered if I can find it.

Or will my end user just have to suffer the consequences of their forgetfulness?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just allowing a password hint, like Windows does?

P.S.  You should never email a password, maybe just a one-use password or a link to reset the password.

Comment: Good suggestion! I like that. Thanks.

And good advice on the emailing of a password too. Thanks again :-)